# Output CSV file and net user command not aligned with PS command

Tags: powershell, layout, format, get-aduser

Below I have a PS command to get some useful user info. I want also have the input from a csv file with PC names. How can I give everything the same format?

The colon after PC name is not the same as I've got from the output from `get-aduser`. Can someone advise me what to do?

[Example of what I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAye1.png)

```
Clear-Host
do {

write-Host " Enter the user ID: " -ForegroundColor Cyan -NoNewline
$UserName = Read-Host
Write-Host ""


Get-ADUser -Identity $Username -Properties * |  Select-Object  DisplayName,  mail, LastLogonDate, LastBadPasswordAttempt, AccountExpirationDate, PasswordLastSet , OfficePhone, Department, Manager
    

$Processes = Import-CSV 'C:\Users\w0vlnd\Desktop\Powershells\Computers in a specific workgroup or domain.csv'
$processes | where "User ID" -like $Username | Select-Object "PC name" 


net user $Username /domain | find "Password expires" 
net user $Username /domain | find "Password changeable" 
write-host "`n"


} while ($Username -notcontains $Processes)
```

Comment: the last two items that you are getting via `net user $UserName` ... where does the data come from? i cannot find it in the properties listed for `Get-ADUser`, but i CAN find it in the output of `Get-LocalUser`.

Comment: I am confused. Is your question that `Net user`, and `Get-ADUser` results don't align for the same user?

Comment: It’s not that the data is nog aligned but it’s the format/ layout that is not the same…

Comment: Is use the netuser command to get data that I cannot get from get-aduser. I’ve got the pc name from a csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct an *object* that merges the AD User with the information coming from your CSV and the information from `net user`. Here is an example of how you can approach it:

```
$csv = Import-CSV 'path\to\csvhere.csv'
$ADprops = @(
    'DisplayName'
    'mail'
    'LastLogonDate'
    'LastBadPasswordAttempt'
    'AccountExpirationDate'
    'PasswordLastSet'
    'OfficePhone'
    'Department'
    'Manager'
)

$filter = @(
    $ADprops
    @{
        Name = 'PC Name'
        Expression = { $pcName }
    }, @{
        Name = 'Password Changeable'
        Expression = { $changeable }
    }, @{
        Name = 'Password Expires'
        Expression = { $expires }
    }
)

Clear-Host
do
{
    Write-Host " Enter the user ID: " -ForegroundColor Cyan -NoNewline
    $UserName = Read-Host
    Write-Host ""

    $pcName = $csv.Where({ $_."User ID" -match $Username })."PC Name"
    $expires, $changeable = net user $Username /domain |
    Select-String -Pattern 'Password Changeable|Password Expires' |
    ForEach-Object { ($_ -split '\s{2,}')[1] }
    Get-ADUser -Identity $Username -Properties $ADprops |
    Select-Object $filter

} while ($csv.'User ID' -notcontains $Username)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly for me!!

Comment: @Toon happy it worked for you. Please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it was useful to you.